# How to un/marshall a Float as a Scala Option[Float] rather than a Java Float with JAXB?

Tags: scala, jaxb

I'm having a problem using JAXB in Scala for marshalling and unmarshalling floats (and integers for that matter).

In my Scala app I have variables like this:

```
val taxPaid: Option[Float]
```

If taxPaid is equal to `0.0f`, it means no tax paid; if taxPaid is equal to `None`, then it means that we don't know how much tax was paid.

A variable like `Option[Float]` maps perfectly onto a SQL `float NULL` column (I use Squeryl), and equally it can be expressed fine within a JSON or XML. The problem I have is with JAXB - to get JAXB working, within my POJO representations I have to use simple Java `Floats`, like this:

```
@XmlElement(nillable = true, `type` = classOf[Object])
@BeanProperty
var taxPaid: Float = _
```

And then, because a Java `Float` cannot take a value of `null`, the value of `0.0f` is treated as an (incorrect and lossy) proxy for `null`.

So my question is: is there a way that I can marshall and unmarshall XML floats to a Scala `Option[Float]`, and thus keep the significance of  the `null`?

Comment: A java `Float` can take a value of `null`, the primitive `float` can't.

Comment: Thanks Ingo - your comment pointed me in the right direction on this one (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ingo**'s comment steered me in the right direction - the problem is that a Scala `Float` cannot be set to `null` (presumably to encourage idiomatic usage of `None`), whereas a Java `Float` can:

```
scala> val nf:java.lang.Float = null
nf: java.lang.Float = null

scala> val nf:Float = null
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Null(null)
 required: Float
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method Float2floatNullConflict in class LowPriorityImplicits of type (x:     Null)Float
 and method Float2float in object Predef of type (x: java.lang.Float)Float
 are possible conversion functions from Null(null) to Float
       val nf:Float = null
                      ^
```

So the answer is just to make sure that my representations explicitly use Java `Floats`:

```
import java.lang.{Float => JFloat}

@XmlElement(nillable = true, `type` = classOf[Object])
@BeanProperty
var taxPaid: JFloat = _
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else comes wondering around, there's also the option of using an adapter so you don't have to deal with nulls in your code. You'd need to provide an implementation of XmlAdapter. There's a guy who blogged about this: http://krasserm.blogspot.com.ar/2012/02/using-jaxb-for-xml-and-json-apis-in.html